# Adding a kind of "metadata" file and read it from a custom action but prevent copying it to the installation directory

Tags: c#, wix

I have an MSI Installer created with WiX Toolset.

Now I need to include a kind of "metadata" file which will contains some information I need to consult during the installation process. This information is not always the same and it varies depending on some conditions.

The build process we have is an automated process through a python script and before building the WiX project and creating the MSI, we create the "metadata" file which is included as a component in the WiX project.

We want to prevent this "metadata" file to be copied in the installation directory. This "metadata" file is read and only used by the installer during the installation process.

so my questions are:

1. How to read the contents of that "metadata" file defined as a component from a custom action in C#
2. How to prevent this "metadata" file to be copied to the installation directory